# Is there a way to customize Android TV OS?

Tags: android, operating-system, television

I want to develop a TV solution that gives me control over some OS-related stuff (like controlling volume level, apps downloads, etc). Something similar to EMM but for TVs. This is to be used for hospitals where certain functionality can be allowed by users.

Is there a way to customize Android TV (even if it requires Google partnership or something)?

If not, are there any other TV operating systems that allow extending/manipulating the OS? Please note that I've explored some "hotel-mode" functionalities from Samsung and LG, and they're not sufficient for my use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android does not need Android TV to be used on a TV. There are plenty of Android-powered set-top boxes on Alibaba, for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare but as far as I understand, using Android Open Source Project (AOSP) prevents me legally from installing apps through Google Play for example. However, using Android TV keeps us within the Android ecosystem. Please correct me if I'm wrong, and pass me some resources to proceed.

Comment: The determination of whether your device qualifies for Google Play is dependent mostly on [a series of legal agreements that your attorneys will need to obtain and review](https://source.android.com/setup/community#for-business-inquiries). "Android TV" does not somehow magically qualify you for Google Play where "AOSP" does not.